# cURL in PHP Basecamp API "PUT"

Tags: php, api, curl, basecamp

I am trying to edit an existing Basecamp project via the new [Basecamp Api](https://github.com/37signals/bcx-api). I am receiving this error:

```
lexical error: malformed number, a digit is required after the minus sign. ---------------      ---------------6 (right here) ------^
```

My Code:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://basecamp.com/****/api/v1/projects/****.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User-Agent : Holy Grail (user@example.com)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("name" => "from cURL"));



$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);


if ($result == false) {
echo "Fetch failed" ;
}
else {
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
}

//var_dump($obj);



?>
```

I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid, but any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

***UPDATE***
 What I have now:

```
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$data = json_encode(array("name" => "from cURL"));

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://basecamp.com/****/api/v1/projects/*****.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User-Agent : Holy Grail     (user@example.com)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                              'Content-Type :application/json',
                                              'Content-Length: ' .strlen($data)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);





$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);


if ($result == false) {
echo "Fetch failed" ;
}
else {
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
}

//var_dump($obj);



?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BasecampAPI accepts only JSON data, you can see here in `-d` parameter -

```
curl -u username:password \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'User-Agent: MyApp (yourname@example.com)' \
  -d '{ "name": "My new project!" }' \
  https://basecamp.com/999999999/api/v1/projects.json
```

So you're not sending JSON data in this line -

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("name" => "from cURL"));
```

Remove the `CUSTOMREQUEST` option and add `CURLOPT_PUT`. Modify your code to -

```
$data_string = json_encode(array("name" => "from cURL"));
...

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);
```

Comment: I am getting a `403 Forbidden` Now. I can't understand why.

Comment: I am using the account holder's login details. I know the user and pass have permissions for the request

Comment: Try putting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` *before* the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` line. Also add `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `True`.

Comment: Check the answer, I've added some more info.

Comment: No I am getting `411 Length Required` and  `HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required Server: nginx Date: Wed, 20 Mar 2013 20:50:15 GMT Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 174 Connection: close`

Comment: Did you add the `'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))` part?

Comment: Yes, I did. I is still giving me the `411`

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect my complete current code

Comment: I wonder.. Try removing `'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))` from the header array.

Comment: I had more luck keeping `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT'` rather than `CURLOPT_PUT, true`.  With `CURLOPT_PUT`, PHP deals with file streams and so forth, whereas with `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is used instead. YMMV.